# Web API doesn't respond to iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, nsurlsession

I have an *ASP.NET* web API action which is called by a specific application on *iOS* devices. It works fine when it is opened in the browsers either on smartphones or desktop. However, smartphone application doesn't get any response when it is called with `httpMethod = GET`. While if I change iOS and server `httpMethod` to `POST`, everything works as intended.

Server code:

```
[HttpGet("{uuid}")]
public async Task<ConfigurationProfileDto> Get([FromRoute]string uuid)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uuid))
        return null;
    var smartphone = _SmartphoneService.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Uuid == uuid && p.StatusId == Data.Entities.SmartphoneStatusEnum.Active);
    if (smartphone == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var profileDto = new ConfigurationProfileDto(smartphone.User.ConfigurationProfile);
 
    return profileDto;
}
```

iOS code:

```
public func requestSend() {
        delegate?.managerDidStartLoading?(request: self.requestObject)
        requestInitialization()
        sessionInitialization()

        let task = session?.dataTask(with: request!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            self.delegate?.managerDidFailed(description: error!.localizedDescription, request: self.requestObject)
            return
        }
        if let status = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            if status.statusCode == 200 {
                self.delegate?.managerDidSuccessed(request: self.requestObject)
                if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) {
                    self.delegate?.managerDidReceived?(data: json, request: self.requestObject!)
                }
            }
            else {
                self.delegate?.managerDidFailed(description: "Server returns code \(status.statusCode)", request: self.requestObject)

            }
        }
    })
    task?.resume()
}

private func requestInitialization() {
    if let urlString = requestURL,
        let url = URL(string: urlString) {

        request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request?.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request?.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request?.httpMethod = "GET"
        request?.timeoutInterval = 120

        do {
            request?.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestParameter!, options: .prettyPrinted)
        }
        catch let error {
            delegate?.managerDidFailed(description: error.localizedDescription, request: self.requestObject)
        }
    }
    else {
        delegate?.managerDidFailed(description: "insufficent request parameters", request: self.requestObject)
    }
}
```

Response header:

```
transfer-encoding: chunked
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
server: Kestrel
date: Sun, 08 Apr 2018 05:23:44 GMT
```

Why doesn't it work well with `httpMethod = GET`?

Comment: a GET request does not accept a BODY, while POST/PUT does. The way you are making the request from the iOS client is the problem. If making a GET request, then there can be no `httpBody`

Comment: @Nkosi Great, thank you. It is fixed now!